# Integrating social plugins - likes disappeared

Tags: facebook-like, integration, facebook-social-plugins

So, researched this forum for the same problem, but still without success, any solutions haven't worked for me.

The problem is that we had four pages which ones have had like buttons. So we launched advertisement campaign, have collected some likes (more than 100 likes per page). Now we added one more like button for entire site and likes for these 4 pages now are equal to 0.
How this happened and where the likes disappeared? I'm new to this project so maybe I'm missed something (like metatags, app ids or etc.)?
Reverting project also haven't helped.

The pages I'm talking about (sorry, for separating links, but the editor wont allow me to post more than 2:

http://www.tradicinekolekcija.lt/
- index.php/kolekcijos-alus/old-port-ale/58
- index.php/kolekcijos-alus/baltijos/17
- index.php/kolekcijos-alus/ekstra-draught/16
- index.php/kolekcijos-alus/baltas/15

Answer (score 0):

Your metadata is all right, you can check the data FB is scraping by using the debug tool. Just paste your pages' urls in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug.

The problem is that in the like buttons you're always using data-href="http://www.tradicinekolekcija.lt/" so you're always showing the like button and the count of likes for the main page. Just update the code in each of the urls' like buttons to point to the right url (the same url of the page where the like button is).

This should fix the issue!